# Retrieve text from video frames via pytesseract

Tags: python

I've been searching through posts trying to find ways of improving performance on the below script but can't seem to get anything to make much difference. Through tests I've managed to conclude that `pytesseract.image_to_data` takes ~.2 seconds each time it's called. Does anyone see an obvious way of improving the speed? I would like to be able to retrieve all of the text information without cropping the image into 3 separate boxes but without doing that it always gets it wrong. Tried psm that recognizes different sized characters but yields poor results. I'm not at all experienced in this area so it's possible I'm just doing something very wrong. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

[image: example image (after cropping)]

```
def preprocess(frame, xy):
    _frame = cv.pyrUp(frame[xy['y1']:xy['y2'], xy['x1']:xy['x2']])
    _frame = cv.cvtColor(_frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    _frame = cv.GaussianBlur(_frame, (3, 3), 0)
    _frame = cv.threshold(_frame, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    kernel = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))
    _frame = cv.morphologyEx(_frame, cv.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)
    _frame = 255 - _frame
    return np.dstack([_frame, _frame, _frame])
```

```
def to_data(frame):
    img_data = pytesseract.image_to_data(frame, config='--oem 3 --psm 7', output_type=Output.DICT)
    return img_data.get('text', [-1])[-1]
```

```
def run(file_name, network, interval, show):
    file = pathlib.Path(PLAYBACK_PATH.format(str(file_name)))
    cap = cv.VideoCapture(str(file), 0)
    fps = int(cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FPS))

    dataset = []

    ix = 0
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if frame is None:
            break
        if ix % (fps * interval) == 0:
            row = []
            for lookup, xy in NETWORKS[network].items():
                _frame = preprocess(frame, xy)
                _data = to_data(_frame)
                row.append(_data)
                if show:
                    cv.imshow('frame', _frame)
                    cv.waitKey(1)

            row.append(ix)
            dataset.append(row)
        else:
            pass

        ix += 1

    cap.release()
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
    return dataset
```

Comment: Instead of making the pytesseract.image_to_data faster, which is very unlike, I would recommend to reduce the number of times this function is called. There is absolute no need for running it in every frame. You can extract like 5 frames per second and continue to reduce this value to fulfill your needs

Comment: @MatheusHaas I'm not exactly sure what you mean. The way it executes right now image_to_data is called 3 times but only on 1 frame per second. Based on what I've read elsewhere it seems as though I should be able to process frames quicker than current performance. Or maybe I'm just completely lost.

Comment: have you tried disabling some of the preprocessing tesseract does internally? As you do your own it could help to avoid doing the same work twice.
Same goes for constructing a three channel image from a gray image. I am pretty sure you can pass the grayscale image directly and avoid tesseract converting it back again.

Comment: @Cube Thank you for the advice. I'm going to try that out and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: what about multiprocessing `for lookup, xy in NETWORKS[network].items():` ?